# In Mysql 5.1, what are table names that look like "#sql-44a5_1bc"?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a foreign key problem that makes absolutely no sense. All conventional reason is unable to solve the problem, and I am at a loss. I think the crux of the problem lies in the fact that one of the error messages is reporting the table '#sql-44a5_1bc'. Does anyone know what this is? What created it? Is this just a hidden name for an actual table?

Here is my foreign key problem too, if you feel like helping with that. It's still unsolved and this is a big problem because this is on a production database:

[Problem adding Foreign Key using Alter Table with existing MYSQL Database - can't add it! Help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672472/problem-adding-foreign-key-using-alter-table-with-existing-mysql-database-cant)

Comment: Suggestion: start **Bounty** for your Question of [FK](http://goo.gl/GdBpb) .you'll surely get the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is the temporary table created during ALTER TABLE. I've seen something similar when I tried to add a fk constraint to a table. The data present in the table violated the constraint I've tried to add, and the error message referenced a table name similar to the one you mention.

[See MySQL-Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html):

> In most cases, ALTER TABLE makes a temporary copy of the original table. MySQL incorporates the alteration into the copy, then deletes the original table and renames the new one.

Comment: Yeah, I've had the same errors. I usually just have a little cry and start over. This explains why though, thanks.